# Form is submitted before jQuery is finished modifying values in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-deferred

Here's what I'm trying to do: when a radio button is clicked, I want to update some values in the form and only after those values are updated, submit the entire form. the problem I'm having is, that the form is submitted before the values are updated.

This is my current (non-working) implementation:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label id="label_radio_2_78" class="btn btn-info btn-sm checkbox-padding ">
        <input onchange="update_transaction(78)" id="radio_2_78" name="ledger_id" value="2" type="radio">
        BR
    </label>
    <label id="label_radio_3_78" class="active">
        <input onchange="switch_ledgers(78, 3)" id="radio_3_78" checked="checked" name="ledger_id" value="3" type="radio">
        HP
    </label>
</div>
```

```
function switch_ledgers(transactionId, ledgerId)
{
    deactivate_radio(transactionId, ledgerId).done
    (
        update_transaction(transactionId)
    );
}
```

```
//checks if the clicked radio buttion is active, if so it unchecks it.
function deactivate_radio(transactionId, ledgerId)
{
    var cb  = $('#radio_' + ledgerId + '_' + transactionId + ':checked');
    var r   = $.Deferred();

    if(cb)
    {
        cb.prop('checked', false);
        $('#label_radio_' + ledgerId + '_' + transactionId).removeClass('active');
    }
    return r.resolve();
}
```

```
//Submits the form, this function gets called too quickly
function update_transaction(transactionId)
{
    var form    = $("#transaction_" + transactionId);

    $.ajax({
        type:   form.attr('method'),
        data:   form.serialize(),
        url:    form.attr('action')
    }).done(function()
    {
        update_balance();
        update_total_balance();
    });
}
```

I hope I made it sufficiently clear what I'm trying to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straightforwardly, you just need to fix `switch_ledgers()` so as not to call `update_transaction()` immediately (Peter Herdenborg's answer).

Going further, you can (and should) :

- purge the deferred/promise from `deactivate_radio()`, which is totally synchronous.
- attach event handlers in javascript, not as HTML attributes.
- avoid cumbersome ids by exploiting the power of jQuery to traverse the DOM.

There must be a thousand ways to write the code - here's one :

**HTML**

Purge ids and `onchange=` properties in favour of `data-` properties

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" data-transactionId="78">
    <label class="btn btn-info btn-sm checkbox-padding">
        <input data-changeHandler="update_transaction" name="ledger_id" value="2" type="radio"> BR
    </label>
    <label class="active">
        <input data-changeHandler="switch_ledgers" checked="checked" name="ledger_id" value="3" type="radio"> HP
    </label>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
// Attach a generalised change handler to the radio buttons, 
// braching out to a specific function as specified by
// the button's `data-changeHandler` property.
$(".btn-group input[type='radio']").on('change', function () {
    changeHandlers[$(this).data('changeHandler')](this);
});

// Branching above is made simple by specifying 
// the specific change handlers as properties of an object.
var changeHandlers = {
    'switch_ledgers': function(button) {
        $(button).filter(':checked').prop('checked', false).closest("label").removeClass('active');
        changeHandlers.update_transaction(button);
    },
    'update_transaction': function(button) {
        var transactionId = $(button).closest(".btn-group").data('transactionId'),
            form = $("#transaction_" + transactionId);
        $.ajax({
            type: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            url: form.attr('action')
        }).done(function() {
            update_balance();
            update_total_balance();
        });
    }
}
```

Now, modify the HTML in other button groups to follow the same pattern as above.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks! I'm still fairly new to front-end development, so your advice was really helpful.

Comment: Cool! Pleased to assist.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're calling update_transaction() directly in the onchange event of the first input element.

Shouldn't you be calling switch_ledgers() in the change event instead?

**For Example:**

```
<input onchange="switch_ledgers(78)" id="radio_2_78" name="ledger_id" value="2" type="radio">
```

Comment: That issue is more obvious than the one I identified, but I think both fixes are probably needed for the whole thing to work.

Comment: I disagree. The OP appears to intend the two buttons to behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem is that you execute `update_transaction()` when you're actually trying to pass it as the callback function of `.done()`:

```
function switch_ledgers(transactionId, ledgerId)
{
    deactivate_radio(transactionId, ledgerId).done
    (
        update_transaction(transactionId)
    );
}
```

should be

```
function switch_ledgers(transactionId, ledgerId)
{
    deactivate_radio(transactionId, ledgerId).done
    (
        function() {
            update_transaction(transactionId)
        }
    );
}
```

If you weren't passing an argument to `update_transaction()`, you could just have used

```
deactivate_radio(transactionId, ledgerId).done(update_transaction); //No ()
```

but now that you do you have to wrap the call in an anonymous function to avoid executing `update_transaction()` immediately.